# Why can i not approve activities in Landscape when installing packages?

Tags: 14.04, landscape, canonical

"x Activities could not be approved"

This is the error I continuously get when trying to approve package installs or removal. Sometimes the activity goes through anyway but half of the time it throws this error at the top of the screen and I cannot go any further. I looked everywhere and it doesn't seem that anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only activities that require approval are the ones with a status of unapproved. If you try to approve any other activity type, it will fail with that error message which is misleading in that regard. It should say that some of the activities that you selected don't require approval.

Comment: Huh... well that certainly is misleading, and why hasn't that been stated anywhere is beyond me. Thanks a bunch anyway!